# c# windows application arrays and string split

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to split the string in C# and I use this code:

```
string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
string[] words = str.Split(' '.ToArray());
```

but I have an error at `Split(' '.ToArray());`I want to split the text and save it as array for example I have:

```
string input = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7';
```

the array to be:

```
string[] array = input.split(' ');
output:
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2 ....
```

I have tried this methods but they don't work I don't know why.

the message from Exception is: `"index was outside the bounds of the array"`

Here is all the code:

```
void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, and BeginInvoke is good practice anyway.
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, e });
                return;
            }

            int maxTextLength = 1000; // maximum text length in text box
            if (tbData.TextLength > maxTextLength)
                tbData.Text = tbData.Text.Remove(0, tbData.TextLength - maxTextLength);

            // This application is connected to a GPS sending ASCCI characters, so data is converted to text
            string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
            //tbData.AppendText(str);
            //tbData.ScrollToCaret();

            string[] words = str.Split();

            try
            {
                tbData.Text = words[1].ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            richD.AppendText(str);
            richD.ScrollToCaret();

        }
```

hope you can help.
or if you have a better Idea to insert the received data in datagridview

Comment: Split method will return string[]. What is your problem.the line str.Split(' '.ToArray()); also wrong.

Comment: the Exception you are receiving would seem to indicate that your `str` has no value.  have you verified in the debugger that `str` does in fact have a value?

Comment: ok so how does the *full code* in the edit match the *partial code* which you posted when asking for assistance originally?  Your question states "I have an error at `Split(' '.ToArray());`, yet your code has `str.Split();`.  it is impossible for us to accurately tell you what code is wrong when you don't post the incorrect code in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is in your question.

In your given code you are trying to split a string without assigning a paraneter.

```
string[] words = str.Split();
```

This will not split the string into multiple part. it will creates only one element in the array. While you are trying to access then 2nd element from index 1 from `word` array.

```
tbData.Text = words[1].ToString();
```

this will give the error that there is no element on index 1 the number of element count in the array is only 1 which is at Index 0.

So, Either you can get string from Index 0 or specify the parameter in `Split()` function.

```
string[] words = str.Split(' ');
```